# conditional future in the past!

Tags: conditionals, future-in-the-past

Which one is correct?

> 1. My stomach was really upset. I felt that I **will** puke if I eat even a morsel of food.

Or

> 2. My stomach was really upset. I felt that I **would** puke if I eat even a morsel of food.

I try to explain the situation:

My stomach was really upset yesterday. Yesterday, when I was suffering from the stomachache, I thought I would puke after eating something, but I didn't eat and I didn't puke!

It was just a feeling that I had yesterday. I felt something yesterday, but now that I'm talking about it, I do not have that feeling anymore.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say. Is the speaker **currently** suffering from a stomach ache  or is the speaker talking about the **past** and how they **felt**  when they **had** such abdominal pains that even the thought of eating **would** make them vomit.

Comment: I would consider both versions to be ungrammatical in any case. P.S not my downvote.

Comment: "...I would puke if I **ate** a morsel..."

Comment: @Mari-LouA I explained it in the question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Will can never be past. Since you have Yesterday I felt.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences in the original post are incorrect

**Incorrect**

> 1. My stomach was really upset. I felt that **I will puke if I eat** even a morsel of food.

The stomach ache and the feeling of nausea both happened in the past but  the result of eating another mouthful of food will occur in the future. This construction is confusing to read and hear.

To talk about a present situation and its possible result in the future:

**Correct**

> My stomach **is** really upset, I **feel** that I **will puke** if I **eat** even a morsel of food.
> OR
> My stomach really **hurts** if I **eat** anything more, I'**ll puke**.

Notice that the verb *eat* in the "if" clause is in the present tense but the result of eating more food happens in the future: *will puke*.

**Incorrect**

> 2. My stomach **was** really upset. I **felt** that I would puke if I **eat** even a morsel of food.

The verb *eat* in the "if" clause should be in the simple past tense.

**Correct**

> My stomach was really upset. I felt that I would puke if I **ate** even a morsel of food.

When we talk about a result that didn't happen in the past, we can also use **would + have + past participle**

**Correct**

> My stomach was really upset. I felt that I **would have puked** if I ate even a morsel of food.
> OR
> My stomach really hurt if I ate anything more, I **would have puked**.

When verb in the "if" clause is in the Past Perfect (e.g. *had eaten*) it means the action did not happen but we can still imagine what the future consequence might be if that action had taken place. This type of conditional is commonly referred to as the *[third conditional](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if)*.

> My stomach was really upset. I felt that I **would have puked** if I **had eaten** even a morsel of food.